# Getting the output of a command in a Bakefile

Tags: c++, compilation, wxwidgets, bakefile

I'm just getting started on a project with wxWidgets, and I'm trying to set up a Bakefile for cross-platform compilation. I need to pass the output of `wx-config --libs` and `wx-config --cxxflags` to the compiler.

How can I accomplish this? I cannot find anything in the Bakefile docs about getting the output of a command into a variable. Backticks don't seem to work:

```
myvar = `wx-config --libs`
#=> bakefile.bkl:2:12: error: no viable alternative at character u'`'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotes here, i.e.

```
myvar = "`wx-config --libs`"
```

For the reference, here is what I do in my own bakefiles:

```
if ( $toolset == gnu || $toolset == gnu-osx ) {
    setting WX_CONFIG {
        default = wx-config;
        help = "Path to the wx-config script";
    }

    compiler-options += "`$(WX_CONFIG) --cppflags`";
    link-options += "`$(WX_CONFIG) --libs`";
}
```

This allows to do things like `make WX_CONFIG=/full/path/to/wx-config` which is handy when using an uninstalled version of wxWidgets.